# How to use remove_if with vector<point2f>

Tags: opencv

I have a vector that has lots of NaN's for x,y positions that I want to remove(doing some opencv work). I cannot figure out how to use remove_if to remove the NaNs(when used in conjunction with erase). I've seen lots of examples if the vector is float or int but not point2f. Any simple examples would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: add some code samples you tried.

Comment: Something like this: vector<point2f> myv; myv.erase(remove_if(myv.begin,myv.end,isnan(myv)),myv.end);

Comment: I am not an expert of opencv. I was telling to Add these to your question and format that properly so that other's can figure out your issue easily. I was from review actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lambda function, or a functor or a function pointer. This is an example with a lambda function:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    vector<Point2f> pts{ Point2f(1.f, 2.f), Point2f(3.f, sqrt(-1.0f)), Point2f(2.f, 3.f) };

    cout << "Before" << endl;
    for (const auto& p : pts) {
        cout << p << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    pts.erase(remove_if(pts.begin(), pts.end(), [](const Point2f& p)
    {
        // Check if a coordinate is NaN
        return isnan(p.x) || isnan(p.y);
    }), pts.end());

    cout << "After" << endl;
    for (const auto& p : pts) {
        cout << p << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

That will print:

```
Before
[1, 2] [3, -1.#IND] [2, 3]
After
[1, 2] [2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks so much Miki!  I'm new to C++ so don't know how that works, but it does/did.  Magic!  I'll be reading up on Lambda functions today.  Cheers.