# Using an Algorithm library operation in a vector array C++

Tags: c++

Is it possible to use an **Algorithm** library operation in a vector array? If so, how am I supposed to do it and what operations could I use here(ex. **remove_if**)? Currently, I'm running a for loop to calculate my score checking if I hit a certain object and deleting it afterwards if it was hit. It all works great, but I somehow need to use an Algorithm library here. (I'm still quite new in C++) Here's what I have so far:

```
std::vector<Coin*>coins;
coins.push_back(new Coin(&window_object[0], 60.0f, 60.0f, 350.0f, 425.0f, "res/coin.png"));
coins.push_back(new Coin(&window_object[0], 60.0f, 60.0f, 450.0f, 425.0f, "res/coin.png"));
```

...

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < coins.size(); i++) {
    if (coins[i]->CheckCollect(player)) {
        Coin* temp = coins[i];
        coins.erase(coins.begin()+i);
        delete temp;
        score++;
    }
}
```

EDIT: code miss-type

Comment: You sure can, you will just have to give it a predicate so it knows how to compare the objects. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35643588/how-to-use-remove-if-with-vectorpoint2f) for an example. You can search "remove_if vector" here on Stackoverflow for many different examples.

Comment: PS: this line `(coins.begin()+i);` really doesn't do anything.

Comment: Why do you have vector of pointers? Vector should be the owner of the objects it stores. If you need polymorphism, use smart pointers. This will make operations like removing elements much easier.

Comment: Look into  `std::find_if` that can use a lambda as predicate and returns an iterator. Since you're pushing items into the vector, you might consider pushing copies or smart-pointer wrapped instances instead of pointers so that you can then use `erase` to delete both the coin and the vector cell that holds it. You could also use `std::shared_ptr` and `std::make_shared` to hold each coin in a smart pointer.
`std::remove_if` can also be used if all you need is to delete.

Comment: Well, yes, it is possible to use standard algorithms on any standard container - typically by passing the `begin()` and `end()` iterators to specify the range, and any other arguments required. BUT the number of algorithms that will work on a vector of dynamically allocated objects, and both `delete` a pointer AND erase that pointer from the vector is much smaller. It would be simpler if you had a `vector<Coin>` and don't dynamically allocate the instance of `Coin` - all standard algorithms can be applied to a `vector<Coin>` (as long as `Coin` supports operations needed by each algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

It's not hard to replace your `for` loop with a standard library algorithm. You're iterating over a vector, doing some work, and possibly erasing some elements. That can be done with `std::remove_if`.

I moved the loop body into a lambda expression and then used that in an `erase/remove_if`:

```
auto my_predicate = [&](Coin *coin) {
    if (coin->CheckCollect(player)) {
        delete coin;
        score++;
        return true; // remove this element
    }
    return false; // don't remove
};

coins.erase(std::remove_if(coins.begin(), coins.end(), my_predicate), coins.end());
```

I don't know if it's cleaner code but it might perform better. The `for` loop repeatedly calling `erase` can be expensive as elements are moved multiple times to fill in the holes. With `std::remove_if` each element is moved at most once and there's a single `erase` to fix the vector size.